# NSMutableDictionary-Error in setting the key value pairs on to the dictionary

Tags: objective-c

I am getting errors for the below code.

```
@interface event : NSObject
{
NSMutableDictionary  m_cAppIdMap;  //error:statically allocated instance of Objective C
}
@end
```

I am setting the object to the dictionary through the function create in the event implementation.

```
[m_cAppIdMap setObject:pEvent forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:wTimerId]]; //Error:Cannot convert to a pointer type
```

This is the way i am setting a structure object on to the dictionary.
pEvent is the structure containing 5 fields and wTimerId is the unsigned short integer(key).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ivar should be a pointer.

```
NSMutableDictionary*  m_cAppIdMap;
```